# How can I make an attraction point using Cannon.js

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I'm using Three.js and Cannon.js.

Also, I'm trying to reproduce [this object](https://youtu.be/ouTLi5SmMuw?t=375) (the multiball one).
Basically, the ball goes from its origin to the pressure point and stops, or rotates around the pressure point (this is called mass-spring).

For the moment I was able to set the direction of the ball via velocity but the ball doesn't stop at the pressure point and the more distance there are the higher the velocity is (I need constant velocity).

I've asked the question on Github and someone told me to have a look at [this example](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/examples/callbacks). The only problem is that it only rotates around a planet where I'm searching how to move a ball to a certain point which doesn't sound to be the same. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a physics model like this one:

```
friction model
m = 2 (it could be also m = 1 or m = 3 or whatever looks good)

coefficients:
cf = coefficient of friction
cs = coefficient of spring

Dynamics / update of position and velocity with time-increment dt

x_cursor = x coordinate of cursor's position
y_cursor = y coordinate of cursor's position

x  =  x  +  dt * v_x
y  =  y  +  dt * v_y
v_norm = sqrt(v_x^2 + v_y^2)^(m-1)
v_x  =  v_x  -  dt * cf * v_norm * v_x  -  dt * cs * ( x - x_cursor ) 
v_y  =  v_y  -  dt * cf * v_norm * v_y  -  dt * cs * ( y - y_cursor )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I'll have a look at it